# Why the hyphen(-) is not printed?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        char* ptr;
        int size;
        while(1){
                int scanfinteger = fscanf(fp,"%d",&size);
                ptr = (char*)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));
                if(scanfinteger != 1){
                        int result = fscanf(fp,"%s",ptr);

                        printf("ptr:[%s]\n",ptr);
                        if(result == EOF)
                                break;
                }
        }
        return 0;

}
```

input_file(argv[1]) contains this

```
10 This
10 is
10 buffers
10 -
10 hi
10     -hello
```

my program's output

```
ptr: [This]
ptr: [is]
ptr: [buffers]
ptr: [10]
ptr: [hi]
ptr: [hello]
```

I can't understand why the hyphen gets consumed. Has someone had seen this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: Your logic seem wrong to me. You read the string only if you fail to read the integer value? The [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) call should return `1` if it reads and parses the integer correctly, `0` if it fails to parse an integer, and `EOF` on errors.

Comment: Exactly! I am trying to read integer first and allocate char array with that integer and store the string into it. Above code just like puesdo to check the output. Sorry.

Comment: If you have actual code that builds (without warnings hopefully) and produces output, then please show us that instead of rewriting something that doesn't work as your real code. Please take some time to  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And of course *copy-paste* (as text) the MCVE into the question body.

Comment: But the code above gives me exactly same output where I am stuck on my actual code. is it too deficient to deal with my issue?

Comment: Apparently the leading hyphens are processed when trying to parse an negative integer. The next character isn't a digit, and so `scanf` decides that the parsing of the number fails, but it doesn't reset the reading position in the stream. (I'm not sure what the expected behaviour is here.) To work around the issue, scan a string first and then parse that with `strtol`.

Comment: @MOehm, that doesn't make sense. The hyphen is after an int was parsed, separated by a space. The int `10` was parsed, now follows a space. The scanning should stop at the space. Scanning a string should include everything from the current position to end-of-line, so the space, the hyphen and the rest.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: It doesn't? The code uses only `fscanf` and hence treats line endings like any other space. All the 10s are parsed correctly.The program tries to parse the words as numbers first, too, and only after that fails are they read as string. I think what I describe is what's actually happening. You can see it by printing the parsed number when the parsing succeeded.

Comment: @MOehm, I see. Didn't see that it parses the string after parsing the int failed.

Answer (score 3):

If I may suggest a different solution, I would suggest you read *lines* and then parse the lines.

Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // First make sure you have enough arguments
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Need an argument!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the file, and make sure we succeeded
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open the file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // Now read the file, one line at a time
    char line[100];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
    {
        // Now we have a line, attempt to parse it
        int value;
        char string[100];
        if (sscanf(line, "%d %99s", &value, string) != 2)
        {
            printf("Failed to parse the current line\n");
            break;  // Break out of the loop
        }

        printf("Read value %d, string '%s'\n", value, string);
    }

    // All done, or we had an error (should probably check that)
    // Anyway, close the file and end the program
    fclose(fp);
}
```

---

The problem with your current code (which doesn't seem to be the actual code you run) is that you only read the string if the reading of the number *fails*.

What the problem is with your actual code, that produces that output, I don't know. But somehow it comes out of sync. This can be seen in that you for one line read the number as the string.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie After fixing a bug, [yes it does](https://ideone.com/OO2bAg).